# How to use mappers for ICollections<Float>

Tags: c#, mapping

I would like to know how to use a mapper class to store a Collection to a database.

The type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'

my Mapper Class

```
            public LocatieMapper()
    {
        //Table
        this.ToTable("Locatie");

        //Properties => Columns
        this.Property(p => p.Naam);
        this.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(p => p.GemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen).IsRequired();

        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(k => k.Id);

        //Relationships

    }
}
}
```

this is my Locatie Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Klimatogrammen.Models.Domain
{
public class Locatie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private String naam;
    private ICollection<float> gemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen;//want to map this
    private ICollection<float> totaleMaandNeerslag;//and this 

    public Locatie(String naam, ICollection<float> gemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen, ICollection<float> totaleMaandNeerslag)
    {

        this.Naam = naam;
        // test

        this.GemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen = gemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen;
        this.TotaleMaandNeerslag = totaleMaandNeerslag;
    }
// other code
```

added constuctor for extra information

example of call constructor

```
    temperatuur = new List<float> { 3.46F, 3.8F, 6.65F, 9.25F, 12.95F, 15.35F, 17.75F, 17.6F, 14.8F, 11.2F, 7F, 4.05F };
        neerslag = new List<float> { 60.5F, 63F, 56.3F, 42.4F, 59.7F, 60F, 77.3F, 88.4F, 73.7F, 68.3F, 80.9F, 82.5F };
        Locatie gent = new Locatie("Gent", temperatuur, neerslag);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using StructuralTypeConfiguration, so the Property method requires an expression describing a function that returns a value type.  `ICollection<T>` is not a value type (indeed, all interface types are reference types).

Try using ConventionTypeConfiguration instead.

Comment: @DaanF what are you passing into the `Locatie` constructor?  Can you post the code that throws the exception?

Comment: `this.Property(p => p.GemiddeldeMaandTemperaturen).IsRequired();`
the exception is thrown here
and just a name and a list of numbers that i want to put in the database

Comment: You have mischaracterized the exception message.  It is not saying that there is a null value.  It is saying that there is a nullable type.  That's entirely different.  I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DaanF I've rewritten the answer.  It looks like you should be using `ConventionTypeConfiguration` instead, which "Allows configuration to be performed for an entity type in a model."  The `Property` method of this type does not have a restriction on its generic type parameter.